# Callback function (PySNMP) in thread blocks other threads from starting

Tags: python, multithreading, pysnmp

I tried this example [PySNMP Trap Receiver](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncio/manager/ntfrcv/transport-tweaks.html#serving-multiple-network-interfaces) in main thread, everything worked fine, but when I start it in multithreading as first thread I can't start my other threads.

1. If I send a trap, all other threads start successfully, without trap nothing works except trap receiver.
2. I've tried `loop.call_soon_threadsafe`, didn't help

```py
    def _callback_func(self, snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName,
                       varBinds, cbCtx):
            execContext = snmpEngine.observer.getExecutionContext(
                        'rfc3412.receiveMessage:request')
            source = (execContext['transportAddress'][0])  # source
            trap_oid = varBinds[1][1]
            value = varBinds[2][1]
            trap=[]
            trap.append(source)
            trap.append(trap_oid)
            trap.append(value)
            self.q.put(trap)
            self.logger.warning(f"[SNMPTRAP] Received trap:{source}, {trap_oid}, {value}")

    def _receiver(self):
            try:
                # Register SNMP Application at the SNMP engine
                ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(self.snmpEngine, self._callback_func)
                self.loop.run_forever()

            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.exception(str(e))

    def _configure(self):
        return self

    def start(self):
        self.worker = Thread(target=self._receiver)
        self._configure()
        try:
            self.logger.info("Starting thread 'trap receiver'...")
            self.worker.start()
            if self.worker.is_alive():
                self.logger.info("Thread 'trap_receiver' started")
                while True:
                    data = self.q.get()
                    self.logger.debug(f"Returned trap {data}")
                    return data
            else:
                self.logger.error("Couldn't start thread 'trap receiver'")
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f"An exception occured while starting thread 'trap receiver' {str(e)}")
```

Comment: I'd advise enabling pysnmp debugging to see where it blocks. Internally, pysnmp does not do any locking (as an asynchronous app). If you are using asyncio main loop, I wonder if that could be the cause...? May be try asyncore loop just to rule out asyncio problem?

Comment: Didn't help. If I run it after all other threads started it works, but I also run uvicorn. In debug I've seen only errors about wrong path to mibs. Python-mibs was installed. I suppose I have to change pysnmp directory to python parent dir, now it's in venv dir